# Best way to implement python flask in AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I'm implementing a service, and need some opinions, as this is my first time working with AWS.

Service as of now:
flask framework, pulls information from database with pyodbc, converts query results into a dataframe, and then with flask, posts the dataframe results to the local server using an html template.

We are looking to move it to Lambda, and I'm finding tons of options online using just lambda & api gateway, and then lambda with flask & zappa & api gateway. I'm looking for the most efficient way to do this.

Can anyone please offer their knowledge?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to look at [AWS Chalice](https://aws.github.io/chalice/index.html) which is an opinionated python micro-framework to develop server-less applications. If you are familiar with Flask, you'd feel at home with Chalice.

It is a bit of work to make pyodbc work in Lambda. You would need to have the native libraries required by pyodbc either packaged along side your code or as a separate Lambda layer. See [this](http://See%20https://medium.com/@narayan.anurag/breaking-the-ice-between-aws-lambda-pyodbc-6f53d5e2bd26%20for%20more%20details) for more details on that.